# Setting the same value for the Same Expression Multiple Times

Tags: vb.net

I'm making, what was meant to be a simple game-ish program. Its going well and its one of the more complicated programs I've made, and the first I've even attempted in years.

I'm trying to build in a constant expression that will change depending on where its used. The problem is I cant remember/am unsure what it is I need to be using.
I'm currently essentially hard-coding the program to avoid errors, the relevant code currently goes:

```
Dim FangOwned

Private Sub PnlFangKnife_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PnlFangKnife.Click

    GoldNeeded = 12

    If GP = GoldNeeded And FangOwned = False Then
        GP -= GoldNeeded
        LblGoldInt.Text = GP
        LblFangInt.Text = "Owned"
        FangOwned = True
        PnlFangKnife.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D

    Else


    End If

End Sub
```

Etc. Etc.

The problem is that at the moment the player has four weapons available to purchase. so I've had to declare a new integer per weapon;

```
Dim FangOwned

Dim CrudeOwned

Dim ElvenOwned

Dim MagicOwned
```

And basically write out that same coding for each declaration, plus have overlaps etc. within the relevant buttons. The usage is becoming pretty complicated... I can do it but I would prefer a simpler way of achieving essentially the same effect.

Keeping in mind I haven't done coding in literally years could someone please help me out here?
What type of declaration can I use to simplify this issue?

Ideally I would like something that I can write:

```
Dim TheIdealDeclaration

PrivateSub Button1_Click

    If TheIdealDeclaration = False then

        TheIdealDeclaration = True

    End If

End Sub

PrivateSub Button2_Click

    If TheIdealDeclaration = False Then

        TheIdealDeclaration = True

     End If

End Sub
```

(And not have those two conflicting)

Comment: You should remove the 2 irrelevant tags, add `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file and format your code to look like code

Comment: Does this mean the player must have the exact amount necessary to buy the Fang? He can't have more gold? ` If GP = GoldNeeded And FangOwned = False Then`

Comment: Good point Mary. Changed that coding now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, unless you want to make your game more complex, you should probably stay as you are. As your code stands at the moment, it would only make things needlessly complex if you wanted to avoid duplicating your code because you would need to add code to decide which `Label` and `Panel`you want to alter the properties of.

If you want to add more weapons and more properties like how much damage it does or whether it has a chance of doing extra damage etc, then I would seriously think about creating a `Weapon` class instead and also think about redesigning your interface.

One possible way would be something like ..

```
Private Sub BuyWeapon(ByRef weapon As Boolean, ByRef goldOwned As Integer, cost As Integer, lbl As Label, pnl As Panel)
    If goldOwned >= cost And weapon = False Then
        goldOwned -= cost
        LblGoldInt.Text = goldOwned.ToString
        lbl.Text = "Owned"
        weapon = True
        pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else


    End If
End Sub
```

You have a sub called `BuyWeapon` which can take parameters for which weapon, how much gold you have, how much it costs and which controld you want to change.

Then, your code would look something like this.

```
Dim FangOwned As Boolean

Dim CrudeOwned As Boolean

Dim ElvenOwned As Boolean

Dim MagicOwned As Boolean

Dim GP As Integer

Private Sub BuyWeapon(ByRef weapon As Boolean, ByRef goldOwned As Integer, cost As Integer, lbl As Label, pnl As Panel)
    If goldOwned >= cost And weapon = False Then
        goldOwned -= cost
        LblGoldInt.Text = goldOwned.ToString
        lbl.Text = "Owned"
        weapon = True
        pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Else


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnBuyFangKnife_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBuyFangKnife.Click
    BuyWeapon(FangOwned, GP, 12, LblFangInt, PnlFangKnife)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnBuyCrudeKnife_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBuyCrudeKnife.Click
    BuyWeapon(CrudeOwned, GP, 20, LblCrudeInt, PnlCrudeKnife)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this helped massively. Its just what I was looking for and all made perfect sense to me :) Thank you again!